# Using "of" twice in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

This is the homepage of XXX department of tamilnadu.
I need to know whether I had used "of" correctly in the above sentence.

Comment: One generally tries to avoid using the same preposition multiple times in a sentence, simply because it can sound repetitive otherwise.  (There no "rule" here, just "good practice".)  But in the above case the dual use "sounds" just fine.

Comment: @HotLicks But _of_ frequently counts as a sort-of exception to that because it is used for making simple genitives, and those are frequently stacked in English. The worst example I remember reading was some history book in the eighth grade or so that said something along the lines of, “Heedful of the wording of the intentions of the framers of the ratification of the constitution of the United States of America…”, with seven _of_’s in a row. Truly ghastly sentence, but probably less so than if it had been any other preposition.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with that construction. You are using the preposition correctly, and the sentence does not sound awkward.

Answer (score -2):

While it might sound strange at first, it is grammatically correct!

Comment: Please explain properly why.

Comment: Because you can use the "of" syntax as often as you like. The Department of Defense of the Nation of Germany is still a correct sentence, because there's is not limit of how often you can connect two words of a sentence with the of-syntax. That's why I said that while it my sound weird to the ear, there is not grammatical rule forbidding it, even if there is no rule explicatly allowing it. The same way that no one would limit your use of "and" in a sentence, even though at some point it might sound strange.

Comment: If of you of think I of can use *of* and *and* and and of and of and whenever I of like in and a sentence, you're mistaken.

Comment: Please show me where I said you can use "of" whenever you like in a sentence. I said that you can use "of" in a construction where it is appropriate. It shows the use of genetive. Where ever a genetive is approriate, you can use it. But there is no one limiting your use of genetives in a sentence. You just ridiculed what I was saying because of course does your sentence not only make no sense, but is also grammatically wrong

Comment: "The same way that no one would limit your use of "and" in a sentence, even though at some point it might sound strange."

Comment: Yes, but still, you couldn't make a sentence like this: And this and is and a and ridiculous and discussion. You get the gist, right? You are just being nit picking here.

Comment: I'm sorry for being picky, I was stuck on a bus. Think about your audience when answering. Someone who doesn't know how to use *of* is clearly still learning. If you post essentially "your sentence is fine", they don't learn much, if anything. If you then say "it might sound sound weird ... noöne will limit your use", that further confuses the issue. They need the grammatical rule explained to them. Why is *of* being used? You can [edit] your answer.

Comment: I get what you mean. I guess my answer would have needed a little more explanation to be truly helpful. I will consider this when answering future questions.